# MiKTeX random repository always picking one that's offline

Tags: miktex2.9, repositories

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.7429 with Windows 10 and when I try to update my packages on the internet it fails because a certain repository server is down. Ok, could just wait for the server get back, but my point is that MiKTeX Console just let me set "Random repository" on its configuration although it's apparently not randomizing anything (it always try to connect with the same problematic server). Besides that, I think I should have the ways to choose a server manually (I'm pretty sure I was able to did that in a recent past, but after an update this is not an option anymore). What is going on with this amazing project?

Comment: I just tried and no problems neither with the random repo, nor with setting a special one.

Comment: Hello Ulrike. Certainly your random repository is not the same of mine (http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN), witch still offline today (9-Jun-2020). And the worst part, of course, is that in Console version 2.9.7429 I just can't set a special one (it doesn't have an interface for this selection).

Comment: I have the miktex console version 2.9.7429 and it has in settings, update and packages a button "change" which allows to choose a repo.

Comment: Thanks for your interest Ulrike. That's weird, because I've got the button "change", same as you, but it only leads me to [this windows](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HstaTCvixl1-HRfSJnxObKwwDAaUQQAt/view?usp=sharing), witch in my case doesn't let me choose a repo.

Comment: simply click on "next".

Comment: Good Lord! How did I miss that? Thanks for your time!